# What is a*<a[j] in pseudocode?

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode

I was trying the time complexity mcq questions given in codechef under practice for Data Structures and Algorithms. One of the questions had a line a*< a[i]. What does that line mean?

I know that if there wasn't an and statement the complexity would have been O(n^2). But the a*< is completely alien to me. I searched for it in the internet but all I got was about the a star algorithm and asterisks! I tried running the program in python with a print statement but it says that * is invalid. Does that mean something like a pointer to the 1st element in the array or something?

Find the time complexity of the following function

```
    n = len(a)
    j = 0
    for i =0 to n-1:
        while (j < n and a* < a[j]):
            j += 1
```

The answer is given as O(n). But there are nested loops so it is supposed to be O(n^2).Help required! Thanks

Comment: There's no fixed standard "pseudocode" language, pseudocode is just a common name for a way to express algorithms in a way similar to real programming languages. Your pseudocode is similar to Python, others could use something similar to C or to Pascal. That means there's really no common frame of reference what different things could mean. And that includes expressions such as `a*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually matter what `a*` means. The question is to determine the time complexity of the algorithm. Notice that although there are two nested loops, the inner `while` loop isn't a full independent loop. Its index is `j`, which starts at 0 and is only ever incremented, with an upper bound of `n`. So the inner loop can only run a maximum of `n` times in total. This means that the overall complexity is only O(n).

Comment: But even i loop gets incremented right? So for every i, j loop runs n times, right? Can you please explain

Comment: @ExponentialScholiast: No, the `j` loop does not run `n` times for each `i`. Notice that `j` is set to 0 only once at the start of the algorithm, and is never reset to 0. So over the whole algorithm, the `j` loop only runs at most `n` times.